# Sleuth and java-based logstash appender failing to parse log pattern

Tags: java, spring, logstash, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have added sleuth/zipkin into my project. I'm using logback, and by default I get very well formatted logs in my console and files as well. I'm also using a logstash appender, and when I look at how kibana presents those logs - I'm not satisfied at all. Here are details:

pom.xml:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Brixton.SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>
```

My logstash appender:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "logstash")
public class LogstashConfig {

private String uri;

@Value("${spring.application.name}")
private String applicationName;

public void setUri(String uri) {
    this.uri = uri;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    final Logger rootLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    final LoggerContext loggerContext = rootLogger.getLoggerContext();

    final LogstashTcpSocketAppender logstashTcpSocketAppender = new LogstashTcpSocketAppender();
    logstashTcpSocketAppender.setName(applicationName);
    logstashTcpSocketAppender.setContext(loggerContext);
    logstashTcpSocketAppender.addDestination(uri);

    final LogstashEncoder encoder = new LogstashEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
    encoder.setCustomFields("{\"application_name\":\"" + applicationName + "\"}");
    encoder.start();

    logstashTcpSocketAppender.setEncoder(encoder);
    logstashTcpSocketAppender.start();

    rootLogger.addAppender(logstashTcpSocketAppender);
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    rootLogger.info("Logstash succesfully configured: application connected to logstatsh server {}", uri);
}
}
```

And this is what I see in kibana:

```
LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:%clr(%5p) %clr([my-app-name,%X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-},%X{X-Span-Export:-}]){yellow} application_name:my-app-name
```

The only thing that is resolved by the log pattern is the application name. Am I missing some configuration? Or maybe there's something wrong in my logstash appender?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Logstash appenders to say the least... The thing that Sleuth does is that it puts the log in a very specific format. If you're not tweaking the logback-spring.xml then your logs should reflect that. Another thing that we're doing is that we're using MDC to fill out the logs. Please ensure that you're using the appender in a proper way. Most probably you have a bug there.

Comment: It turned out, that changing log pattern did the trick. I removed this part __%clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p})__ and logs started to look good in ELK.

Comment: Great to hear :) If you need anything else you can also always find us on Gitter https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth

Comment: Can we mark this as answered or sth? :P